# Testing and iterating on a large OpenSearch Index

Tags: opensearch

We're working with an OpenSearch index containing hundreds of millions of documents.

On regular occasions we need to make changes to how data is indexed or enriched prior to indexation without breaking a series of tests.

The issue is that indexing that many documents takes hours, making iterations extremely impractical.

The main solution we see is working with a lighter index using only a subset of all documents relevant to the tests. But it is not straightforward to ensure we've selected every single document needed to maintain e.g. term frequency especially when using fuzzy search, synonyms, etc.

I'm assuming this is not an uncommon situation but don't have extensive experience with OpenSearch, are there any common methods of solving this issue?